# Best framework for developing real-time website?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, frameworks, rendering

The title may be misleading many, so let me rephrase. What is the best framework or language that is used for displaying real-time data, that requires a lot of UI/backend rendering?

Recently I was using mean stack with angular2 for a project and it was very cumbersome for always using two-way data-binding or using event emitters to watch any change.

Is there any language/framework that just renders UI based on what has been changed in backend or frontend?

Would reactjs or metoeorjs do the job?

Please enlighten me.

Thanks

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* Unfortunately, you can't delete this now since two users have left answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A lot of people are straying away from Angular due to the huge changes in 2 in my experience.

Personally, I use react to do this. If you set up web sockets, or use Firebase all you do is handle the event triggers. When they do, react uses immutability to see what part of objects have changed and renders/updates elements accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I understand where you're coming from, but then isn't that very much meteorjs? Because since reactjs is V in MVS, doesn't that limit it to only the view? Whereas meteorjs is full-stack no?

Comment: React is the whole application. Each component is created and you handle the stores and states. If you want a server side then yes you need something like Node.js which is super simple and built for that. it just hosts the already built react application.

Comment: I see, thank you for your response!

Comment: The answer you have accepted and the followup comments give bad advice. The answer you are looking for is: yes - meteor is exactly the tool you are looking for. Using the Meteor data system (publications and subscriptions) all data in the view layer is reactive. That means that as soon as something changes in the DB the view layer will update to reflect the changes. You can use either react, angular or blaze with Meteor but all 3 have exactly the same effect with regards to reactive data.

Comment: Right, make sense @Sean

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure of what would have changed with Angular2 but Angular JS was developed to among other things, make something like that easy.

Since Angular 2 has added much more and streamlined how things are done I'm going to say you don't have a good grasp on what the capabilities are because that should be able to handle that. If not, then Angular JS(1) can for sure.